# How to save settings for Synaptic (Graphical package manager)?

Tags: linux-mint, synaptic, dot-files

I have dotfiles where I store the settings from all the programs that I use. I mean files with the extension `.conf`, `.cfg`, `.rc` and etc.

But I cannot find a place where the Synaptic keeps its settings.
I saw some answers where people talked about `/root/.synaptic` directory. But I do not have access to this directory. And even if I get access to the directory - is it safe to do something inside `/root/` directory?

For example, I want to add more columns and change the toolbar view:
[image]

*system*: Linux Mint 19
*synaptic*: 0.84.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synaptic saves its settings in `~/.synaptic/synaptic.conf`, using the home directory of whatever user runs it. The user is generally root since that’s necessary for Synaptic to make changes, so yes, the settings are usually stored in `/root/.synaptic/synaptic.conf` (and that’s perfectly safe, it’s root’s home directory).

Some settings which affect Synaptic, albeit not the GUI, are general APT settings, stored in various files in `/etc/apt`.